# Should I use LingPipe or NLTK for extracting names and places?

Tags: nlp, nltk, lingpipe

I'm looking to extract names and places from very short bursts of text example

```
 "cardinals vs jays in toronto"
 " Daniel Nestor and Nenad Zimonjic play Jonas Bjorkman w/ Kevin Ullyett, paris time to be announced"
"jenson button - pole position, brawn-mercedes - monaco".
```

This data is currently in a MySQL database, and I (pretty much) have a separate record for each athlete, though names are sometimes spelled wrong, etc.

I would like to extract the athletes and locations.
I usually work in PHP, but haven't been able to find a library for entity extraction (and I may want to get deeper into some [NLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) and [ML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) in the future).

From what I've found, [LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/) and [NLTK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_Language_Toolkit) seem to be the most recommended, but I can't figure out if either will really suit my purpose, or if something else would be better.

I haven't programmed in either Java or Python, so before I start learning new languages, I'm hoping to get some advice on what route I should follow, or other recommendations.

Comment: "... a separate table for each athlete ..."  maybe you mean a _record_ for each athlete?   (that would be an awful lot of tables otherwise...)

Comment: yeah! languages/modules would be the least of my problems if I had a seperate table for each athlete!  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're describing is [named entity recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_entity_recognition). So I'd recommend checking out the other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/named-entity-recognition) regarding this topic if you haven't already seen them. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163923/methods-for-geotagging-or-geolabelling-text-content#164722) looks like the most useful answer to me.

I can't really comment about whether NLTK or LingPipe is best suited for this task although from looking at the answers it looks like there's quite a few other resources written in Java.

One advantage of going with NLTK is that Python is very accessible as a language. The other advantage is that the [NLTK book](http://www.nltk.org/book) (which is available for free) offers an introduction to both Python and NLTK at the same time, which would be useful for you.